# SQLite FTP download / upload issue

Tags: php, windows, linux, sqlite

is have a bunch of SQLite databases on a Linux server.
I recently made a backup of them.
The site where the databases where crashed and I had to reupload all the files.

Now the SQLite databases don't work anymore.
The server is running Linux and I have Windows installed, but the files were only downloaded and they were never opened locally.
Plus I made sure I download them from the server overnight so the nobody was communicating with the file at the time.

I read (now, after the damage has been done) that I have to use some sort of SQLite API to make backups which I didn't know at first.

So my question is - is there any way to save these malformed files? And why are they malformed in the first place?

Tnx!

EDIT:
I am able to query `SELECT * FROM sqlite_master` on the database files, but nothing else...

Comment: So what have to tried to repair those databases? Google suggests a whealth of hit when searching for 'repair sqlite database'...

Comment: well, nothing so far beacuse I'm still trying to figure out how and why a simple download could cause this... but, I'm searching for a good aricle source on sqlite repair right now

Comment: Did you set the `binary` file transfer when uploading/downloading the files?

Comment: well.. I don't know, I'm using FileZilla with the default settings.. could that be the problem?

Comment: What do you see when you do a .dump from the commandline sqlite. Filezilla's default mode is auto so you should be good there. Issues if any could be due to database in use when you copied.

Comment: @Himanshu Yes, but the "auto" mode forced ASCII download... .dump doesn't work - I tried it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making copies of SQLite files is perfectly OK as long as nobody is currently writing to them.

FileZilla's default transfer mode usually is *not* binary, so it is likely that this has corrupted your database files.

When using ASCII mode for FTP transfers, all bytes that look like a line ending (10 in Unix, 13 in OS X, 13+10 in Windows) are converted to the line ending style of the target system.
Afterwards, it is not easily or automatically possible to determine what the original bytes were, so for practical purposes, the databases are unrecoverable.

Comment: Yes... This is exactly what caused the issue... So FTPing the file from the server to my hard drive (for backup) malformed the file because the transfer wasn't binary and now there's no way to save the data.... Great...